# When I use Kartik Editable Widget I got error - Uncaught TypeError: elem.replace is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, kartik-v

In my **Yii2 Framework** project I have a form where I am using **Kartik Editable Widget** for input. There is two rows with this widget. When I open my first input and entering something, in my console appears error message like - '**Uncaught TypeError: elem.replace is not a function**'. But second input works as I expect. As I understood there is some conflict in jQuery but I can not figure out where. Both 'delivery_comment' and 'loyality_comment' are varchar(250). Here is code of my View file:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'delivery_comment') ?>
  <br>
  <?= Editable::widget([
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute'=>'delivery_comment',
                        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXTAREA,
                        'formOptions' => [
                            'id' => 'form-delivery-'.$model->stor_number, 
                        ],
                        'options' => [
                            'class'=>'form-control',
                            'rows'=>5, 
                        ],
                    ]); 
  ?>
  <?= Html::error($model, 'delivery_comment') ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'loyality_comment') ?>
  <br>
  <?= Editable::widget([
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute'=>'loyality_comment',
                        'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXTAREA,
                        'formOptions' => [
                            'id' => 'form-loyality-'.$model->stor_number, 
                        ],
                        'options' => [
                            'class'=>'form-control', 
                            'rows'=>5, 
                        ],
                    ]); 
  ?>
  <?= Html::error($model, 'loyality_comment') ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. Here is the full error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: elem.replace is not a function
>   at Function.buildFragment (jquery.js:5114)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.domManip (jquery.js:5387)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery.js:5218)
>   at jQuery.fn.init. (jquery.js:5333)
>   at jQuery.access (jquery.js:3491)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.html (jquery.js:5300)
>   at showError (editable.js:93)
>   at Object.error (editable.js:168)
>   at fire (jquery.js:3099)
>   at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)

Comment: can you get a screen grab of the complete trace from the console?

Comment: Sure! Here it is:

`Uncaught TypeError: elem.replace is not a function`
`at Function.buildFragment (jquery.js:5114)`
`at jQuery.fn.init.domManip (jquery.js:5387)`
`at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery.js:5218)`
`at jQuery.fn.init. (jquery.js:5333)`
`at jQuery.access (jquery.js:3491)`
`at jQuery.fn.init.html (jquery.js:5300)`
`at showError (editable.js:93)`
`at Object.error (editable.js:168)`
`at fire (jquery.js:3099)`
`at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)`

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to format post in comments....

Comment: you can add the trace inside the question, it wont be readable here. also you are not using the latest version of the widget, as the line numbers for the editable.js not match the line numbers in the latest https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-editable/blob/master/src/assets/js/editable.js

Comment: I edited my question and added complete trace. Thank you for your fast answer. I will try to update.

Answer (score 1):

I got this bug only in first cell of the table, and Make fake cell.
This is not good but it works.

```
'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
'attribute' => 'fakeColumn',
'filterOptions' => ['class' => 'hide'],
'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'hide'],
'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'hide'],
```